# repeat sequences from vector

Tags: r, indexing

Say I have a vector like so:

```
vector <- 1:9
#$ [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

I now want to repeat every `i` to `i+x` sequence `n` times, like so for `x=3`, and `n=2`:

```
#$ [1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 5 6 4 5 6 7 8 9 7 8 9
```

I'm accomplishing this like so:

```
index <- NULL
x <- 3
n <- 2
for (i in 1:(length(vector)/3)) {
  index <- c(index, rep(c(1:x + (i-1)*x), n))
}
#$ [1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 5 6 4 5 6 7 8 9 7 8 9
```

This works just fine, but I have a hunch there's *got to be a better way* (especially since usually, a for loop is *not* the answer).

Ps.: the use case for this is actually repeating rows in a dataframe, but just getting the index vector would be fine.

Comment: Are you looking for this? `rep(seq(vector[1:x]), n)`

Comment: or this: `unname(unlist(rep(split(x, factor(sort(rank(x)%%3))),each=2)))` where `x` is your vector

Comment: nope, don't think so, that only seems to repeat the *first* `1:x` elements n times, I want it for every `i:i+x` element as in the above example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to first `split` the vector, then use `rep` and `unlist`:

```
x <- 3  # this is the length of each subset sequence from i to i+x (see above)
n <- 2  # this is how many times you want to repeat each subset sequence
unlist(lapply(split(vector, rep(1:(length(vector)/x), each = x)), rep, n), use.names = FALSE)
#  [1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 5 6 4 5 6 7 8 9 7 8 9
```

Or, you can try creating a `matrix` and converting it to a vector:

```
c(do.call(rbind, replicate(n, matrix(vector, ncol = x), FALSE)))
#  [1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 5 6 4 5 6 7 8 9 7 8 9
```

Comment: perfect, that does the trick – I just edited in the var names